# $T\colon \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be a linear transformation with $T(x)=0$ for all $x$ such that $||x||=1.$

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following problem that says:

> Let $T\colon \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be a linear transformation. Assume that  $T(x)=0$ for all  $x$ such that $||x||=1.$ Then, which of the following options is correct
>
> 1. $T \equiv 0$
> 2. $T$ is onto
> 3. The dimension of the kernel of $T$ is $1$
> 4. The dimension of the range of $T$ is $1$

I do not know how to progress with the problem and in particular how to use the fact that $\|x\|=1.$ Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.
**EDIT**:As David Mitra suggested,we see that $T(0,1)=T(1,0)=0.$ And so from here.I can conclude that dim(ker $T$)=$2$. So the dimension of range of $T=0$. So,option $2,3,4$ can not be true.So the only option left which is  $T \equiv 0$ is true.Am I right? Please comment.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Can you post your attempts?

Comment: So, $T(1,0)=T(0,1)=0$ ...

Comment: Hint: There are two specific vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which have norm $1$ and which you often use for looking at linear transformations.

Comment: Notice that the set of all $x$ such that $||x||=1$ is a circle; any vector is a scalar multiple of a vector on this circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By linearity, any transformation is determined by its action on a basis. The conditions of your problem allow you to conclude that $T(1,0)=T(0,1)=(0,0)$ as David pointed out. So, you have only one one option that is valid, as you have chosen. But, what does it mean if $Ker(T)$ has dimension 2 and the domain of your transformation has dimension 2? The earlier information allows you to conclude option (1) directly.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** $$T(x)=T\left(\|x\|\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)=\|x\|T\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right).$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: The point is that $T(x)$ is equals to a scalar multiply of $T(y)$ for some $y$ satisfying $\|y\|=1$.